# Loading Bundles One Time in MVC4 Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

With an MVC project containing _layout.cshtml with bundles loaded, clicking around loads the Layout and bundles every time a view is loaded.  Is there any build-in mechanism that I can use to load that stuff only initially, so that RenderBody() only loads the content I don't have yet (not reloading Layout)?  Is this where partials come in?

If partials are the right way to handle it, does this mean I need to have two versions of each controller method (One with Layout, one without)?  Any tips here would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there's no built-in mechanism to load the layout page only at once. You can do it using client-side approach if you want that layout will be loaded only at once so that it would be lighter for the server. Here's the step. Create MVC 4 application.

**In your _Layout.cshtml add a div that will hold the html page you want to load. In my case "pageholder"**

```
 <div id="body">
            <div id="pageholder">
                @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
                <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                @RenderBody()
                </section>
            </div>
 </div>
```

**Add this script in your _Layout.cshtml**

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/common.js")
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.pagelink').click(function() {
                    var settings = {
                        'url': $(this).attr('url'),
                        'type': 'GET',
                        'dataType':'html'
                    };
                    get_html(settings);
                });
            });    
</script>
```

**Modify your menu link**

```
<nav>
    <ul id="menu">
     <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
     <li><a href="#" class="pagelink" url="/home/about">About</a></li>
     <li> <a href="#" class="pagelink" url="/home/contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
</nav>
```

**Add js file and name it common.js and put this content**

```
function get_html(settings) {
        settings.success = function(data) {
            $('#pageholder').empty().html(data);
        };
    settings.error = function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.statusText);
    };
    $.ajax(settings);
}
```

**Set Layout = null; both About and Contact views**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
    Layout = null;
}
```

**Run the application and test the About and Contact pages**